# Smooth (perlin) noise fill for polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

Often times I find myself wanting to add a little bit of texture to polygons. I think something like a smooth noise fill could be kinda cool. Yet, I am a little lost on how I could do something like this in qgis. The idea is:

- To not use an image fill
- Not use multiple shapeburst-fills

It could look similar to this:

[image]

which I took from this blogpost:

https://wheregroup.com/blog/details/30daymapchallenge-und-die-openweathermaporg-api/

Any ideas would be super welcome!:)